# Dynamic panel textbook

Tags: econometrics, applied-econometrics, paneldata, gmm

which books do you recommend for understanding dynamic panel models including Arellano-Bond, System GMM, etc? Ideally intuitive and not too advanced.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Baldagi Econometric Analysis of Panel Data

Answer (score 1):

You can also see JM Wooldridge  Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data.
It is best for you if you follow a testbook by doing econometrics with a software. Princeton used to have onlne spme tutorial on stata. A youtube channel econometrics academy I think was called had also some tutorials with codes